# Geth service gets killed on multiple concurrent requests of web3.personal.importRawKey function

Tags: concurrency, ethereum, rpc, wallet, geth

I have an ethereum-POA node setup on a VM having below mentioned configurations. Using NodeJS Web3 client, I am trying to create new wallets using the web3.personal.importRawKey function.

VM Configurations Azure VM - Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)

As part of our Stress testing, I tried concurrently creating the wallet for 5-10 users, it worked. But when I try to create 15-20 wallets concurrently then the geth process gets killed abruptly and the node stops. On a 1 CPU, 4 GB memory VM, I was able to create at max 4 concurrent wallets. While on 2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory CM, I could process max 10-12 concurrent users.

My concern is the number of concurrent users wallet creation compared to the RAM seems very low and I can't understand why geth processes get killed.One thing I observed was the CPU percentage goes to 200% and then kills the geth node pr

How would I be able to handle at least 1000 concurrent requests to the above-mentioned function to create Blockchain wallets?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!